# Alter table programmatically in MySql

Tags: mysql

**Please note: I need to do this *programmatically*.** I didn't tag any programming language since the language used is irrelevant.

I need to write a function that, given any column from any table, will alter that column so that it accepts NULL (rather than NOT NULL), or change its data type (changing it altogether, or allowing more space to a VARCHAR).

I will only mention the NULL/NOT NULL for simplicity.

I am aware that I can do:

```
 SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE table_name='jobs';
```

Or the simpler:

```
SHOW COLUMNS FROM `jobs`;
```

I can run this through Node (but the same applies to PHP, or whatever) and have data back.

So, for example I can know that `job` has a column called 'name' and that it has NOT NULL.

I realise that I can run `ALTER TABLE jobs ...`. However, *I want to leave the jobs table unchanged, other than 'NOT NULL'; however, `ALTER TABLE` expects a full definition for the table.*

Basically, as far as I can tell, I need to:

- Retrieve the column definition from `SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE table_name='jobs';` and place it into a data structure
- Change the definition returned (e.g. YES rather than NO in the 'Null' key)
- Create an ALTER TABLE statement that reflects the changed structure
- Issue that ALTER TABLE statement

Is this the right path? If so, how do I get a full ALTER TABLE statement starting from the data I received about the table?

Or, is there a way to make a "hard change" via API without issuing an ALTER TABLE statement?

Comment: I would programmatically do `show create table yourtablename`, and find the line for the column to change.  parsing and changing just the type or nullability should be fairly simple.  then prepend `alter table yourtablename modify column ` and run it

Comment: For this question, I would really love to know why the hell it was downvoted. Seriously

Comment: Wasn't me.  People vote strangely, especially on questions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is definitely no way to change the type or nullability or other attributes of a column without using `ALTER TABLE`.

You can execute an `ALTER TABLE` statement programmatically, via the same API you use to run queries from any client application code.

I think you're mistaken when you say `ALTER TABLE` requires the full definition for the table. It does require the full definition for the *column* you want to modify. But you don't need to mention other columns. They are left unchanged.

You can use additional terms of your WHERE clause to get only the details for a specific column:

```
SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE table_name='jobs'
  AND column_name='name';
```

Comment: I meant "Full definition of the column". However, I won't change the question so that your answer still makes sense. And thanks for the answer!

Comment: Ok, I thought you might have meant that, but then your information_schema query was not restricting by column name, and I thought you were fetching all the details for _all_ columns and forming a large ALTER TABLE statement for all the columns. Not necessary - but I've seen people do stuff like that.